# Date regexp failing

Tags: karate

I have some troubles making regexp validation work: for example with

```
startDate: '#regexp \\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}',
```

I get

```
startDate, actual: '2020-06-03', expected: '#regexp \d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}', reason: regex match failed
```

while on a test website it matches.

What am I getting wrong?